# How to make a mpandroidchart horizontol-chart draw from right to left

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I use `MPAndroidChart` in my project, today I meet a problem,please look the screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaxuN.jpg)

I know how to implement the left diagram，but I don't know the right how to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer:

`XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
 xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.TOP);`

`YAxis leftYAxis = barChart.getAxisLeft();
 leftYAxis.setInverted(true);`